# "Invisible" breakpoint when debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-juno

I'm working with Eclipse Juno. When I debug a desktop application, the debug stops at a line of code wich doesn't has a breakpoint configured. Any idea why this could be happening?

I want to remove it because i'm not interested in debugging that line.

Thank you

Comment: Possible reason may be, you have a library associated to your project and that library project has a debug point. You can disable it there.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to un-select

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Debug : Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions
```

Comment: Thank you, I removed the breakpoint from the list of breakpoints. The weird thing was that the breakpoint couldn't be removed from the code itself..